# Instana REST API, 405 error - how to fix?

Tags: rest, instana

trying to get receive informations via the Instana REST API. Looks like that:

```
https://[URL]/api/application-monitoring/metrics/applications?'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"timeFrame": {"windowSize": [SIZE], "to": [SIZE]}, "metrics": [{"metric": "calls", "aggregation": "SUM"}, {"metric": "errors", "aggregation": "MEAN"}, {"metric": "latency", "aggregation": "MEAN"}, {"metric": "latency", "aggregation": "MIN"}, {"metric": "latency", "aggregation": "MAX"}], "nameFilter":"[NAME]"}'
```

Getting back that error:

```
{
  "code": 405,
  "message": "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"
}
```

The matching Curl script (which I can't use) looks like that and works:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: apiToken <APITOKEN>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"timeFrame": {"windowSize": [SIZE], "to": [SIZE]}, "metrics": [{"metric": "calls", "aggregation": "SUM"}, {"metric": "errors", "aggregation": "MEAN"}, {"metric": "latency", "aggregation": "MEAN"}, {"metric": "latency", "aggregation": "MIN"}, {"metric": "latency", "aggregation": "MAX"}], "nameFilter":[NAME]}' [URL]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

That endpoint requires a POST, it appears you are using GET. Hence method not allowed.

Comment: I thought "POST" is supposed to be used when writing something into a field or anything?

Comment: The documentation clearly states POST https://instana.github.io/openapi/#operation/getApplicationMetrics Think of it this way, you POST a query object to get the results you want. If it were done via GET it would need a lot of query params and be a bit messy.